# What iOS component is this? (Look at the picture)

Tags: ios, cell, separator

Hi guys I've trying to figure out which iOS component is the one in the picture below (the one pointed by the arrows), its like a cell separator that gets stuck at the top while the bottom keep scrolling, you can also find it in the address book with the alphabet. If you happen to know any tutorial any tutorial also post it too. Thank you very much!

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is the section header in a UITableViewController or a subclass of UITableViewController (subclasses are used so you can write your own custom code). You can check out the [Stanford cs193P](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/) course for more information. Table Views are covered in the 9th week.

Answer (score 1):

Thats the TableView's section header